# Connecting elements using Jquery by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block which contains a few buttons, I want a user to be able to connect element as he/she wishes. a connector can be svg, also assume elements can be draggable

I want something like this below

[image]

So far here is what I have, [jsfidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6ZuS/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="elm">Div 1</div>
<div class="elm">Div 2</div>
<div class="elm">Div 3</div>
<div class="elm">Div 4</div>
<div class="elm">Div 5</div>
<div class="elm">Div 6</div>
<div class="elm">Div 7</div>
<div class="elm">Div 8</div>
<div class="elm">Div 9</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", "div.elm", function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("connected")) return;

  if ($(this).hasClass("highlight")) {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    return;
  }

  if ($("div.highlight").length == 0) { 
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
  } else if (!$(this).hasClass("connected")) {
    // there's one clicked already so lets connect em
    var div_1 = $("div.highlight")
    var pos_1 = div_1.position();
    var div_2 = $(this)
    var pos_2 = div_2.position();
    if (pos_1.top == pos_2.top) {
      // same row
      if (Math.abs(pos_1.left - pos_2.left) == 100) {
        // adjacent
          var bar = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : (pos_1.top - 2 + div_1.height() / 2) + "px", "height" : "5px", "width" : "50px", "left" : ((pos_1.left > pos_2.left ? pos_2.left : pos_1.left) + 50) + "px" });
          $("body").append(bar);          
      } else {
        // same row not adjacent
          var bar1 = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : (pos_1.top + 50) + "px", "height" : "20px", "width" : "5px",  "left" : (pos_1.left - 2 + div_1.width() / 2) + "px"});
          var bar2 = bar1.clone().css({"left" : (pos_2.left - 2 + div_2.width() / 2) + "px"});
          var bar3 = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : (pos_1.top + 65) + "px", "left" : ((pos_1.left > pos_2.left ? pos_2.left : pos_1.left) + 25) + "px", "width" : "200px", "height" : "5px" });
          $("body").append(bar1).append(bar2).append(bar3);
      }
    } else if (pos_1.left == pos_2.left) {
      // same column
      if (Math.abs(pos_1.top - pos_2.top) == 100) {
        // adjacent
          var bar = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : ((pos_1.top > pos_2.top ? pos_2.top : pos_1.top) + 50) + "px", "height" : "50px", "width" : "5px", "left" : (pos_1.left - 2 + div_1.width() / 2) + "px" });
          $("body").append(bar);          
      } else {
        // same column not adjacent
          var bar1 = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "left" : (pos_1.left + 50) + "px", "height" : "5px", "width" : "20px",  "top" : (pos_1.top - 2 + div_1.height() / 2) + "px"});
          var bar2 = bar1.clone().css({"top" : (pos_2.top - 2 + div_2.height() / 2) + "px"});
          var bar3 = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "left" : (pos_1.left + 65) + "px", "top" : ((pos_1.top > pos_2.top ? pos_2.top : pos_1.top) + 25) + "px", "width" : "5px", "height" : "200px" });
          $("body").append(bar1).append(bar2).append(bar3);
      }
    }
    div_1.removeClass("highlight").addClass("connected");
    div_2.addClass("connected");
  }    
});
```

Css

```
div.elm { 
    float:left; 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#9F9;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

div.elm:nth-of-type(3n + 1) { clear:left; }
div.elm:nth-of-type(3n) { margin-right:0px; }
div.highlight { background-color:#F99; }
div.connected { background-color:#99F; }
div.connectbar { 
    position : absolute; 
    z-index : 10; 
    background-color:#66C;
}
```

so far my demo is connecting the only element in the same row, I can't connect the way I want.

What do I need to change to get the result I want? or is there any plugin which can solve my problem?? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at libraries like https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/ ?

Comment: I would also suggest a library. This kind of feature is very hard to create. Another one: https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph